# Keyboard in iOS increases in size before getting dismissed

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

So I am trying to work with **additionalSafeAreaInsets**, when the keyboard comes up it works fine but when It gets dismissed notification registers a slight frame increase before decreasing to a certain value (I am using **custom input accessory view**). Can anyone help me identify what exactly is causing that increase in size it is leading to weird animation where everything rises and then falls after a delay. I know I should be using NSLayoutConstraints instead of additionalSafeAreaInsets instead, but for a specific use case, I need to work with them only.

I tried all notifications (will show, did show etc to get frames).
I tried putting in animations using UIViewPropertyAnimators.
Before getting dismissed keyboard **frame height goes like 384 -> 418 -> 82**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.